# Rotating Triangle around True centre?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have created the following draw function:

```
function draw(ctx, scale, angle) {
    // DRAW SHAPE:
    var rotation = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
    var h = scale * (Math.sqrt(3) / 2);
    var radius = h / 4;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#BE1942';
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF2159";
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = radius;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(getCX(), getCY());
    ctx.rotate(rotation);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, -h / 2);
    ctx.lineTo(-scale / 2, h / 2);
    ctx.lineTo(scale / 2, h / 2);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -h / 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();

    // RESET:
    ctx.restore();

    // FINALIZE:
    ctx.save();
}
```

I have noticed that when I rotate this triangle, it does not rotate around the true centre, but much rather at an offset. Is there a simple way to make it rotate around the true centre? I assumed it should already do that since I am drawing it from the centre coordinates.

Comment: you need to translate the center of rotation  before rotating and restore it afterwards, set up a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your x,y do not add up to 0,0, but to (0, h/2)

```
ctx.moveTo(0, -h / 2);
ctx.lineTo(-scale / 2, h / 2);
ctx.lineTo(scale / 2, h / 2);
```

So modify your translation, or say

```
ctx.moveTo(0, -2*h / 3);
ctx.lineTo(-scale / 2, h / 3);
ctx.lineTo(scale / 2, h / 3);
ctx.lineTo(0, -2*h / 3);
```

Comment: Was in the process of making a Fiddle. Thank you for your quick response. Worked like a charm.